# Bounds on real numbers

Tags: analysis, real-numbers, upper-lower-bounds, machine-precision

Suppose that $\{\epsilon _1 , · · · , \epsilon_m \} $are real numbers that all satisfy $|\epsilon_i | ≤ \eta$. Show
that given $C > 1$, we have that
$$ \Pi_{j=1}^m(1+\epsilon_j) = 1 + \epsilon$$where $|\epsilon| ≤ Cm\eta$, provided that $0 < \eta ≤ \min\{ log \frac{C}{m-1}, 1\}$. For double precision
arithmetic how large can we take $m$ if $C = 2$?

Comment: do you want the sum to be $m+\epsilon$ instead of $1+\epsilon$?

Comment: also, why does the title say "multiplication"?

Comment: @mathworker2 The sum should be $1 + \epsilon$

Comment: I mean obviously this problem is false. Take $\epsilon_j = 0$ for all $j$. Then the sum is $m$, which means $\epsilon$ is $m-1$ but $Cm\eta$ is less than $m-1$ if $\eta < \frac{1}{2C}$, say, which is true for $m$ large enough.

Comment: @mathworker21 My bad, it is not a sum, it is multiplication. Edited the question.

Comment: I have the feeling you are copying this question from somewhere and haven't thought about it yourself